# Обратное число, олимпиадная задача

Tags: python, олимпиада

Помогите, моя программы по мнению тестовой системы Сириуса работает слишком долго. Помогите ускорить мою программу.
Вот само задание:

Обратное число

В этой задаче нужно ответить на 1≤t≤10<sup>5</sup>
запросов. Каждый запрос состоит из двух целых чисел 2≤p≤10<sup>9</sup> и 0<a<p, число p является простым. На каждый запрос нужно вывести в отдельной строке целое число 0<b<p, такое что (a⋅b<sup>−1</sup>) ⋮ p.

Входные данные:

В первой строке дано целое число t — количество запросов. В следующих t строках даны по два числа p<sub>i</sub> и a<sub>i</sub>, i=1,... ,t.

Выходные данные:

Выведите: t целых чисел (каждое число в отдельной строке) — ответы на запросы.

Примеры:

Ввод:

```
4
5 1
5 2
5 3
5 4
```

Вывод:

```
1
3
2
4
```

Ограничения:
Время выполнения: 5 секунд

Вот мой код:

```
b = []
for x in range(int(input())):
    a = list(map(int, input().split()))
    b.append((a[1]) ** (a[0] - 2) % a[0])
print('\n'.join(map(str, b)))
```

Comment: Каким образом из ввода получается вывод? Причём здесь обратное число и что это такое?

Comment: Программу можно ускорить так `b.append(pow(a[1], a[0] - 2, a[0]))`, но работать она все равно будет некорректно. В условии не сказано, что модуль - простое число, а это необходимое условие для того, чтобы a^(p-2) было сравнимо с a^(-1) по модулю p. Воспользуйтесь расширенным алгоритмом Евклида

Comment: @extrn, _`число p является простым`._

Comment: @Qwertiy видимо начинаю слепнуть :)

Comment: @MBo, не дубликат. Там условия другие - ни простота модуля не гарантируется, ни существование обратного.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Обратное число к а по модулю m](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1139455/%d0%9e%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be-%d0%ba-%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8e-m)

Answer (score 2):

Длинная арифметика медленная. А по условию тебе вообще не нужны числа больше 10<sup>9</sup> (и 10<sup>18</sup> в промежуточных операциях). Так что придётся использовать [бинарное возведение в степень по модулю](https://e-maxx.ru/algo/binary_pow).

Comment: @extrn, я не знаток питона и не знал, что там такая есть. Удалил из ответа часть про самостоятельную реализацию.