# Обратное число к а по модулю m

Tags: python, python-3.x, алгоритм, математика, теория-чисел

Обратное число
Даны два целых числа m и a. Если не существует обратного числа к a по модулю m, то выведите число −1, а если существует, то выведите это число (ответ должен лежать в границах от 0 до m−1).

Входные данные
В единственной строке входных данных даны два целых числа 1

Выходные данные
Выведите ответ на задачу.

Примеры
Ввод
179 57
Вывод
22

```
b = 0 
a = list(map(int, input().split())) 
b = pow(a[1], a[0] - 2, a[0]) 
if pow(a[1], a[0] - 2, a[0]) == 0: 
    print(-1) 
else: 
    print(b)
```

Comment: Приведите, пожалуйста, свой код, покажите - в чём не можете конкретно разобраться...

Comment: b = 0
a = list(map(int, input().split()))
b = pow(a[1], a[0] - 2, a[0])
if pow(a[1], a[0] - 2, a[0]) == 0:
    print(-1)
else:
    print(b)

Comment: У меня не проходит по времени

Comment: зачем pow 2 раза?

Comment: У условия убрать pow?

Comment: да, оно уже посчитанно в b - второй раз не нужно

Comment: Пишет, что программа выдает неверный ответ

Comment: @Manulova_dasha, немного не понимаю вас, что значит - не проходит по времени?

Comment: Неверный ответ, потому что решение такое работает только для **простых m**

Comment: "Программа выдает неверный ответ" вот что пишет.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Решение с использованием расширенного алгоритма Евклида. Способ через степень требует вычисления функции Эйлера. [e-maxx](https://e-maxx.ru/algo/reverse_element)

```
def gcdExtended(a, b):
    if a == 0 :
        return b,0,1
    gcd,x1,y1 = gcdExtended(b%a, a)
    x = y1 - (b//a) * x1
    y = x1
    return gcd,x,y

m, a = map(int, input().split())
gcd, x, y = gcdExtended(a, m)
if gcd == 1:
    print((x % m + m) % m)
else:
    print(-1)
```